# Proving sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing

Let $ a(n) = \frac{2n-1}{2n} $. Prove that the sequence is decreasing for $ 0 < a(n) <= \frac{1}{5} $ and then prove that the sequence converges to $ A $ that is an element of the reals where $ 0 \leq A < \frac{1}{2} $.
I am really unsure how to do this and a step by step process would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Hint to find the limit:

$$a(n)=\frac{2-\frac1{n}}{2}$$

Are you sure the sequence is decreasing?

Are you sure $A<\frac12$? you might want to check again.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence is actually increasing:

$$ a_{n+1} - a_n = \frac{ 2(n+1) - 1 }{2(n+1)} - \frac{2n-1}{2n} = \frac{1}{2n^2+2n} > 0 $$

And notice $a_n = \frac{ 2n - 1 }{2n} < \frac{2n}{2n} = 1 $

boundedness and monotonicity $\implies$ $(a_n)$ converges.

Please, fill in the details.